# Typecasting for functions with different arguments in c

Tags: c, casting, function-pointers, typedef

So I have two functions that does the same thing but on different type variables.

The first function fills up an array of integers when given an `int arr[]` argument.
The second function fills up a linked list with integers also when given a struct as an argument.
The struct for the linked list argument looks something like this

```
typedef struct {node_t *head;int size;} 
list_t;
```

Now I have implemented a table of function pointers for the two functions as such:

```
typedef struct{
    char *name;  //name of the function
    void (*fill)(int arr[]); //fill up the array 
} alg_t;

alg_t algs[] = {
    {"func1",fill_up_arr},
    {"func2",fill_up_linkedList}
};
```

Notice that inside the struct that holds my pointers, the fill function pointer 
takes `int arr[]` as an argument.

I only want one pointer of a function in that struct, is there a way I can use
typecasting so that other functions such as `fill_up_linkedList` require argument to be of type list_t instead of `int arr[]`?

```
//This is what I want my main to look like.
//I want func.fill to be called only once thus
//dynamically perform the operations for all functions inside the table of 
//functions array
int arr = malloc(sizeof(int)algs.size);
for(int i = 0; i<algs.size;i++){
     alg_t func = algs[i];  
     func.fill(arr);
}
```

It seems that the problem with this code would be when the loop would try and perform the `fill_up_LinkedList` function as it needs a different argument.
How can I use a typecast in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: `funcs_t algs[]`? you mean `alg_t algs[]` right?

Comment: yes thanks. Just edited it

Comment: If you are calling all the function on your list with the same input (`arr`) then all the functions would have the same argument types, so there's no problem here.

Comment: There will be a problem since fillUp_linked_list takes a different argument. It will be looking for a struct but instead it would find an int arr[]

Comment: *"I only want one pointer of a function in that struct,"* Do you mean you want to remove `name` leaving only the function pointer? If you want to call two separate functions, you are going to need 2-pointers, unless you do something with a `union` like @Matthias suggests below. (then you must manually control which was the last-assigned pointer)

Answer (score 1):

#### The good news

[C11 §6.3.2.3 Pointers ¶8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8) (under the general topic [§6.3 Conversions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3)) says:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
>   type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted
>   pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
>   the behavior is undefined.

That means you can store any and all function pointers in a common function pointer type, for example `typedef void (*GenericFunctionPointer)(void)`.  What is crucial, though, is that you convert from that generic function pointer type back to the correct function pointer type before you invoke the function via the pointer (and that you provide the correct argument list, and that you handle the return type appropriately, though ignoring the return value, if any, is always an option).

#### The bad news

For two different function pointer types, each with one instance of the the function, the infrastructure needed to support this is probably more elaborate than the savings, if any.  On the other hand, if you have two or more different function pointer types, and most if not all of the types have many representative functions ('many' meaning 'more than one', as in the computer engineer's counting: "zero, one, many"), then the infrastructure can pay off.  One of the issues is marshalling the function arguments — how are the arguments made accessible so that the function can be called via the pointer with the correct arguments.

So, doing things this way is complex and verbose.

#### The stated requirement

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745568/typecasting-for-functions-with-different-arguments-in-c#comment86506171_49745869), the OP [Moi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5400402/moi) says:

> I only want to put one function in the struct. My goal is to find a way to allow `fillArray` to allow the passing of different args.

I have major reservations about the use of an uncounted array as the argument list as shown in the question — `void (*fill)(int arr[])` is shown.  In my view, it should be `void (*fill)(size_t n, int arr[n])`, using the variable length array notation.  You can omit the `n` in the subscript if you wish — `void (*fill)(size_t n, int arr[])` — or even use `void (*fill)(int arr[], size_t n)`, which is the more classic order for the arguments.

Putting this concern aside, if you want a single function to accept different arguments, one way to achieve that is with `void *` as the type, but you have to be aware of the problems — one of which is type safety.  You'll also need to borrow ideas from the standard C functions `qsort()` and `bsearch()`.  The argument list will include the pointer to the start of the array as a `void *`, the size of each element of the array, and the number of elements in the array.  You may also need analogues to the comparator functions.

Internal to the single called function, though, you will probably end up with two code paths, so although you call a single function via the pointer, you end up doing the equivalent of implementing two functions.  You could use an interface similar to `qsort()`'s so that the two functions have the same interface and different bodies, and you use two pointers in the `alg_t` array.

#### Summary

- You probably can't achieve the stated requirement cleanly.
- You will probably need two logically separate functions to handle the two separate interfaces, even if you smush all the code inside a single function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a union:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;  //name of the function
    union {
        void(*fillArray)(int arr[]); //fill up the array 
        void(*fillList)(YourListType list); //fill up the list
    };
} alg_t;

alg_t a;
a.fillArray(...);
a.fillList(...);
```

Or:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;  //name of the function
    union {
        void(*fillArray)(int arr[]); //fill up the array 
        void(*fillList)(YourListType list); //fill up the list
    } functions;
} alg_t;

alg_t a;
a.functions.fillArray(...);
a.functions.fillList(...);
```

Comment: I only want to put one function in the struct. My goal is to find a way to allow fillArray to allow the passing of  different args

Comment: @Moi: Perhaps you are looking for variadic functions? As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C

Comment: You might add initialization of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 2 types, you can just use an enum and a macro

```
enum e_type {e_foo,e_bar};
#define do_foobar(e,...) (e)?bar(__VA_ARGS__):foo(__VA_ARGS__)
```

replace foo and bar with your function names

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the problem with the function parameters and not with the return value, there's a trick related to incomplete type definitions.  The trick consists in leaving empty the list of parameters in the pointer type declaration, as in:

```
 typedef void (*callback_ptr)();
```

which is different from:

```
 typedef void (*callback_ptr)(void);
```

in the first case, the compiler will not check the parameters passed to the function, as the pointer is a pointer to an incompletely defined function type, while the second explicitly says the function doesn't require parameters and will give you an error if you try to call it with them.